Getting import suggestions for a ts.Type object
I'm using the TypeScript compiler API, and I want to find out which module(s) export a given ts.Type. Basically, I need to implement this function:
/**
 * If `type` is exported from a node_modules package, `moduleName` contains
 * that package name, e.g. `{ "moduleName": "react", "memberName": "Dispatch" }`.
 *
 * If `type` is exported from another file, `moduleName` contains the relative
 * path from `containingFile`, e.g. `{ "moduleName": "./useFoo.js", "memberName": "FooState" }`.
 *
 * If `type` doesn't have a name, or is not exported from its containing file,
 * this function returns `null`.
 */
function findImportSpecifierForType(
  type: ts.Type,
  containingFile: string
): { moduleName: string; memberName: string; } | null {
  // TODO
}

Here is my use case why I need this function: I'm building a tool that generates React boilerplate code, stuff like context definitions. Each context instantiation must have a generic type parameter specifying the value type. I extract this type information from existing source files using the TypeScript compiler API.

In the screenshot below, the variable setState is of type Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>. I figured out how to parse source files, and I'm able to extract a ts.Type object that represents the Dispatch type. Now I need to figure out from where I can import this type.

Since VS Code can give me import suggestions, there probably exists something similar in the typescript compiler already. Or would I have to use the language service for this?
